# How to connect to a remote kernel in a ipynb file?

Tags: python, ssh, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to know how to use a remote AWS instance as the backend for my ipython notebook that I have running locally. I typically use [nteract](https://github.com/nteract) as the frontend for my jupyter notebook.

**Motivation:** is that my macbook doesn't have an Nvidia GPU, so I'd like the computations done on my P2 instance remotely, but with the notebook running locally.

This is my first question, so please be gentle :)

Comment: Why has this been closed for being too broad? This is a very pertinent question for anyone running machine learning via IPython notebooks on AWS P2 instances. It's tightly targeted to exactly the issue I've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you ssh to an AWS instance using something like

```
$ ssh -i key.pem username@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

You can local forward to a port, say 8888, with

```
$ ssh -i key.pem -L 127.0.0.1:8888:127.0.0.1:8888 username@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This will forward anything running on localhost at port 8888 on your AWS instance, to localhost 8888 on your MacBook.

Then on your AWS instance, launch an ipython notebook

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888
```

and then on your MacBook, open a browser and navigate to `localhost:8888` and you'll be using the notebook from your AWS instance (which has GPU support).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that works! And by the way, do you know how I would attach Nteract or any other frontend to the remote server?

Comment: Hmm, I'm unfamiliar with nteract but it looks like a cool project.  I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Though now the notebook is running remotely, too - while the original question was on connecting a *local* notebook to a remote kernel.